# Why running this angular test throws "unrecognized expression"?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

My directive is this

```
angular.module('My.directives').
 directive('documentIcon',
   function(MyService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      aDocument: '=',
      user: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/partials/documentIcon.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.alignBottom = 'alignBottom' in attrs;

        //business stuff 
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

My template html is this

```
<span
</span>
```

yeah ... I watered it down after I thought there were empty spaces or special chars.

When I run my spec which is this

```
describe('directives', function() {
    var elm, scope;

    beforeEach(module('My.directives'
      '/partials/documentIcon.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope;
    }));

    it('should have the correct isolate scope values', inject(function($compile) {
      scope.detailDocument = {
        id: 'xyz',
        isChangingActiveState: true,
        public: true,
        starred: true
      };

      scope.user = {
        id: "12435"
      };

      elm = angular.elment('<span document-icon a-document="detailDocument" align-bottom></span>');
          $compile(elm)(scope);

      scope.$apply();

      console.log(elm);
    }));
  });
```

I get this

```
  Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: angular.module('/partials/documentIcon.html', []).run(function($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('/partials/documentIcon.html',
          '<span>\n' +
          '</span>');
      });
          at ......project/web/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
          at ob (......project/web/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
          at xb (......project/web/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
          at db (......project/web/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
          at ......project/web/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
          at ......project/web/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
          at ......project/web/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
          at removeComments (......bower_components/angular/angular.js:8352)
          at ......bower_components/angular/angular.js:7935
          at processQueue (......bower_components/angular/angular.js:13248)
          at ......bower_components/angular/angular.js:13264
          at ......bower_components/angular/angular.js:14466
          at ......bower_components/angular/angular.js:14282
          at ......bower_components/angular/angular.js:14571
          at /......test/helpers/angular-spec-helpers.js:28
          at invoke (......bower_components/angular/angular.js:4203)
          at workFn (......bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2436)
          at ......bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2408
          at /......test/helpers/angular-spec-helpers.js:29
          at /......test/unit/directives/documentIconSpec.js:31
      undefined
```

The template does not have anything special in it.
**Why am I getting this error?**

Comment: where you're declaring module in your HTML ?

Comment: I am using grunt plugin which caches templates at test time and makes it available as a module.

Comment: Show me more code please

Comment: there isnt more to show. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

I've just fixed an error that looks just like this for myself, so I thought I'd post what I discovered here as it's a relatively recent question.

You're using the [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) package, and what is happening is that the code that declares the angular module to cache your template is being loaded as the template, rather than just the template HTML.

The reason that this happened to me was that I was inadvertantly also running another preprocessor, [karma-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-html2js-preprocessor), over the same set of files. I suggest that you have a look for something like this in your karma.conf.js

```
preprocessors: {
  '**/*.html': 'html2js',
  // ... other preprocessors
  '**/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
},
```

You'll want to make sure only one of them is running over your templates.